# Upper semi Fredholm operator is closed map

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from a Banach space X to X and given that $T(X)$ is closed and $ker(T)$ is finite dimensional.I want to prove that for any image of any closed set $M$ is closed i.e T takes closed sets to closed sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is not true.

Consider $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R} = (x,y)\to y$  it is linear with finite dimensional kernel  and surjective.
Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the graph of the $\tan^{-1}(\cdot)$, then $\Gamma$ is closed  but $\pi(\Gamma)  = (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ is not closed.

It is true though that if $S\lhd X$ is a closed subspace in $X$ then $T(S)$ is closed.

Indeed, since $Ker(T)$ is finite dimensional it is complemented in $X$ i.e. $X= Ker(T) \oplus K_1$ with $K_1\lhd X$ a closed subspace of X.
Notice that $K_1 \approx X/Ker(T)\approx T(X)$ (thanks to the open mapping theorem you gain that the obvious map is an homeomorphism).

Now, if $S$ is a closed subspace (hence a Banach) of $X$ then $T(S) = T(S + Ker(T))$ and $T(S+Ker(T))$ is closed since $\frac {S+Ker(T)} {Ker(T)}$ is a Banach space* hence complete hence closed as a subspace of $ \frac X{Ker(T)}\approx T(X)$

*If you quotient a Banach space by a closed subspace the result is still a  Banach.

Comment: but this statement is proved in the book "SEMI-FREDHOLM OPERATORS,PERTURBATION THEORY AND LOCALIZED SVEP" by pietro aiena.but  I have some difficulty in that proof

Comment: Maybe it says  that the image of a closed SUBSPACE is closed, which I can prove.

Comment: okay , please give me proof for closed subspace

Comment: nice proof.....please help me to proof this

Comment: which step is not clear?

Comment: it is all clear but I want to prove also  that there exist a finite dimensional subspace $W$ such that $S =S \cap K_1 +W$

Comment: I have proved that $ S \cap K_1 \oplus S \cap ker(T)  \subseteq S$ but I do not know how to prove reverse part

Comment: I am asking for reverse part $S \subseteq S \cap K_1 \oplus S \cap ker(T)$

Comment: here $W=S/{S \cap K_1} $ how can we say that it is $S/K_1$

Comment: From linear algebra $S = S\cap K_1 \oplus W$ for some $W$ (here $\oplus$ is only algebraic, it do not implies that $S\cap K_1$ is complemented as a Banach space). Consider the map $S\to X \to \frac X K_1$ where the first map is the inclusion and the second one is the projection. The kernel of this map is $S\cap K_1$ and the image is $S/K_1$. It follows from elementary algebra that $S/(S\cap K_1)\approx S/K_1$ which is finite dimensional. Thus $W\approx S/(S\cap K_1)$ is finite dimensional. If you find the answer useful,  accept and rate it please.